snowflake javascript proc variable setting
I have the below code in which I'm trying to insert a value from SQL statement into a variable.
And then use this variable value to build out the file name. But I keep getting error.
Error along lines of "JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in FINANCE_REPORTS at ( select  "
I can get the whole proc to work and even generate the file in blob if I hardcode the date. But eventually this will need to be automated for whatever month job is running ; or previous month. I have added a sample row below and the exact column name [FILE_NAME_POSTFIX] that needs to be part of .gz zip file name. Any help would be great.
CREATE or replace procedure  "SP_MONTHLY_FINANCE_REPORTS"()
RETURNS VARCHAR(10000)
language javascript
as
$$


var ReturnVal = 'REPORT PROC EXECUTION Complete';

var TMP_DATES_crt = `create or replace temporary table TMP_DATES AS 
select *
, case when len(FISCAL_PERIOD) = 1 then concat( to_varchar(FISCAL_YEAR) ,'0',to_varchar( FISCAL_PERIOD) )
when len(FISCAL_PERIOD) > 1 then concat( to_varchar(FISCAL_YEAR) ,to_varchar( FISCAL_PERIOD) ) 
end as File_Name_PostFix
,concat(to_varchar(FISCAL_YEAR),' - ',to_varchar( FISCAL_PERIOD) ) as File_FiscalYear_FiscalPeriod_concat
from (
select a.FISCAL_YEAR,a.FISCAL_PERIOD ,b.MONTH_END_DATE
from (
select FISCAL_YEAR , FISCAL_PERIOD,BEGNNING_DATE_PV
from  Calendar
         where FISCAL_PERIOD >= 1 and FISCAL_YEAR = year( CURRENT_date() )
         and FISCAL_PERIOD = ( month( CURRENT_date() ) - 1 ) 
           and FISCAL_PERIOD_WEEK = 1 and FISCAL_PERIOD_DAY = 1
) as a
FULL OUTER join (
select FISCAL_YEAR , FISCAL_PERIOD, (BEGNNING_DATE_PV -1 ) as MONTH_END_DATE
from  Calendar
         where FISCAL_PERIOD >= 1 and FISCAL_YEAR = year( CURRENT_date() ) 
         and FISCAL_PERIOD = ( month( CURRENT_date() ) ) 
           and FISCAL_PERIOD_WEEK = 1 and FISCAL_PERIOD_DAY = 1
) as b on a.FISCAL_YEAR = b.FISCAL_YEAR
) as c ;`;
var TMP_DATES_crt_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: TMP_DATES_crt});
var TMP_DATES_crt_res= TMP_DATES_crt_stmt.execute();
/* here is the sample data for this if you wish to engage
FISCAL_YEAR FISCAL_PERIOD   MONTH_END_DATE  FILE_NAME_POSTFIX   FILE_FISCALYEAR_FISCALPERIOD_CONCAT
2024    3   2024-03-30  202403  2024 - 3
*/

var THEDATE = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `select FILE_NAME_POSTFIX from TMP_DATES`});
var result = THEDATE.execute();
/*trying to put 202403 value where THEDATE IS BELOW but keeps erroring out. */
var File_1_crt = `copy into @StagingAzure/FINANCE/TEST_Summary_`+ THEDATE +`_.gz
from ( Select 1
FROM PERIOD_SUM
 
 )
SINGLE=true file_format=(type=csv null_if = ('NULL', 'null')
  empty_field_as_null=false) MAX_FILE_SIZE = 150000000 OVERWRITE=TRUE ;`; 
var File_1_crt_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: File_1_crt});
var File_1_crt_res= File_1_crt_stmt.execute();  


var ReturnVal = 'REPORTS EXECUTION Complete';

return ReturnVal;
$$


@junketsu, Seems like you're try to build a query and fire the same to get the filename. In this case you will have to capture the query results into a variable then refer the same in COPY into statement. But you're referring the variable which is holding the SELECT statement used to generate the values. If your query is returning only one row then use below snippet for capturing the query result into variable.
I'm not sure on the use case for generating the date for filename. It can be generated using simple select using date functions in snowflake. But for now I'll share the syntax for capturing query result into variable. I just used * in SELECT to pull all the columns and export them into different variable if you want for any other use case scenarios.
var THEDATE = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `select * from TMP_DATES`});
var result = THEDATE.execute();
/*Capturing query result into variable, each column value will be exported to separate variable*/

while(result.next()){
fiscal_year=result.getColumnValueAsString(1)
fiscal_period=result.getColumnValueAsString(2)
mon_enddate=result.getColumnValueAsString(3)
filename_posix=result.getColumnValueAsString(4)
file_fiscal_period_concat=result.getColumnValueAsString(5)
}
var File_1_crt = `copy into @StagingAzure/FINANCE/TEST_Summary_`+ /*use whatever variable you want from above*/ +`_.gz


your my hero. Thank you. This worked and upvote shared.
